# Shipping and billing addresses dissapear when close and open the page

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft2

I have the following problem. When I set shipping and billing address on my cart and exit the page, the addresses are cleared once I open the page again. Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Thanks, 
Kamen

Comment: Are the items in the cart remaining? Commerce 1.x or 2-beta?

Comment: The items are there, only the addresses disappear.

It's Commerce 1.x